How to correctly merge two object types?
I am working on a TypeScript generic for merging objects, but I encountered an issue where test case t11 is failing.
I would like to understand the reason behind it and how to modify MergeTypesWithPriority to make all the test cases pass.
MergeTypesWithPriority aims to prioritize types from T and have recursive logic when the type is an object.
type Expect<T extends true> = T
type Equal<X, Y> =
  (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? true : false

  type MergeTypesWithPriority<T, U> = {
    [K in keyof T | keyof U]: K extends keyof T
        ? K extends keyof U
            ? T[K] extends object
                ? U[K] extends object
                    ? T[K] extends any[]
                        ? T[K]
                        : U[K] extends any[]
                            ? U[K]
                            : MergeTypesWithPriority<T[K], U[K]>
                    : T[K]
                : T[K]
            : T[K]
        : K extends keyof U
            ? U[K] extends object
                ? T extends Record<K, any> 
                    ? U[K] extends any
                        ? T[K]
                        : U[K]
                    : U[K]
                : U[K]
            : never;
};


type t1 = Expect<Equal<MergeTypesWithPriority<{ a: string }, { a: number }>, { a: string }>>;
type t2 = Expect<Equal<MergeTypesWithPriority<{ }, { a: number }>, { a: number }>>;
type t3 = Expect<Equal<MergeTypesWithPriority<{ a: number | undefined }, { a: number }>, { a: number | undefined }>>;
type t4 = Expect<Equal<MergeTypesWithPriority<{ a: { b: number } }, { a: { b: string } }>, { a: { b: number } }>>;
type t5 = Expect<Equal<MergeTypesWithPriority<{ a: { c: number } }, { a: { b: string } }>, { a: { b: string; c: number } }>>;
type t6 = Expect<Equal<MergeTypesWithPriority<{ a: string }, { a: any }>, { a: string }>>;
type t7 = Expect<Equal<MergeTypesWithPriority<{ a?: number }, { a: any }>, { a: number | undefined }>>;

interface Items { foo: number; bar: { baz: number[] }}
type t8 = Expect<Equal<MergeTypesWithPriority<{ a: Items[] }, { a: any[] }>, { a: Items[] }>>;
type t9 = Expect<Equal<MergeTypesWithPriority<{ a: string }, { a: Items }>, { a: string }>>;
type t10 = Expect<Equal<MergeTypesWithPriority<{ a: any }, { a: Items }>, { a: any }>>;
type t11 = Expect<Equal<MergeTypesWithPriority<{ a: Items }, { a: any }>, { a: Items }>>;

Playground

Uhhh that's fairly complicated for a Stack Overflow question. Your problem is that any is an unsound type, so T extends any is always true, and any extends T is always true except when T is never.  If you want to detect any you need to do it specifically. If I make the changes for that as shown in this playground link your test cases work. If you still have edge cases those are probably out of scope. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

Your example solved my problem (at least I haven't found any new cases so far), please supplement your answer.

The any type is intentionally unsound. It acts as both a top type like unknown and as (nearly) a bottom type like the never type. any is assignable both to and from every other type (except that any is not assignable to never).  That means many of the conditional types in your code will behave differently from your expectations if the type being checked is any.  Your U[K] extends object check passes if U[K] is any. So does the U[K] extends any[] check.  And the U[K] extends any check always passes.
So when U is {a: any} then your example code decides that the a property is an array and returns it. Oops.
If you want to handle any in a special way, you'll need to change your check.
The only reliable way I know how to do this is as described in Typescript check for the 'any' type and Disallow call with any and it takes advantage of the unsoundness. TypeScript will convert just about every union and intersection with any to any.  Something like 1 extends (0 & T) seems like it's always false, since supposedly X extends (Y & Z) requires both X extends Y and Y extends Z.  And since 1 extends 0 is false, that should always be false too.  But if T is any, then 0 & T is also any (unsound, unsafe, but intended), and then 1 extends any is true.  So you can use the unsoundness to detect any.
I will rewrite some relevant bits of your code:
type MergeTypesWithPriority<T, U> = 1 extends (T & U & 0) ? T : { // <--
    [K in keyof T | keyof U]: K extends keyof T
        ? K extends keyof U
            ? T[K] extends object
                ? U[K] extends object
                    ? T[K] extends any[]
                        ? T[K]
                        : U[K] extends any[]
                            ? 1 extends (U[K] & 0) ? T[K] : U[K] // <--
                            : MergeTypesWithPriority<T[K], U[K]>
                    : T[K]
                : T[K]
            : T[K]
        : K extends keyof U
            ? U[K] extends object
                ? T extends Record<K, any> 
                    ? 1 extends (U[K] & 0) // <--
                        ? T[K]
                        : U[K]
                    : U[K]
                : U[K]
            : never;
};

The check at the top bails out early if either T or U are any, and returns T if so. The check in the middle fixes the problem you had with misclassifying any as an array, by just returning T[K] if U[K] is any before proceeding. The check at the bottom changes your U[K] check so it actually looks for any (although I didn't see any examples where it matters).
Let's test your code:
type t11 = Expect<Equal<
  MergeTypesWithPriority<{ a: Items }, { a: any }>, 
  { a: Items }>
>; // okay

All your other tests pass, and now this one does also.
Playground link to code
